# Write to Application Insights from within an ASE

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have an app running in an Application Service Environment (ASE). I now need to the app to start pushing logs to Application Insights.

Can someone tell me if this is possible? Do I need to open up firewall routes to allow access to App Insights, or is there another official way to do this?

Comment: Not sure how it differs from using AI in a 'normal' app service environment. Data is send using https so there is only outbound traffic on port 443. Have you already integrated AI into your web app?

Comment: Not yet, but wanted to make sure it was going to work first. Thanks.